# Pass parameter as attribute in SAML SSO body from Salesforce as IDP

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have setup SSO between Salesforce (Identity Provider) and Connecture (Service Provider).

I have create a connected App for SSO.
SSO is working fine as user is able to login to Connecture with Salesforce credentials.

Connecture supports relaystate to configure landing url in Connecture and I am able to set this up as well.

The blocker is, I want to pass some information from Salesforce to Conencture with Tagert URL in Connecture. I am struggling to do so.

Connecture says that You can pass parameter in the Body of SAML assertion.

Here is where I stuck and I don't know how to pass it or where to configure it.